# How to set the path to xstream in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, import, path, classpath, xstream

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and installed my version of jdk using

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Now I installed **xstream 1.4.7**, but whenever I compile any java files using the package, I get an error telling me that it can't find the `com.thoughtworks` package:

```
$javac app.java

error: package com.thoughtworks.xstream does not exist
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
```

I've checked that it is correctly installed and  I have it in my `/usr/share/java`. After Googling I've found out that I have to set the `$CLASSPATH` variable, however, I don't even have such a variable in my system.

Neither `echo $JAVA_HOME` nor `echo $CLASSPATH` spit anything to the term (I also tried with parentheses), however compilation and execution have both been working perfectly for any other commonly used packages.

My conclusion is that the paths are set in some other place (?).

I also don't have any `export` set for `$PATH` in my **.bashrc** and **.profile** files, so I have no idea where or how to tell the java compiler to find the xstream package.

Everything else is working perfectly in my system. Can anybody point me to the right direction? A simple CLI command to find the path that my compiler is using and add the xtream path to it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the xstream jar file by hand:

`$ javac -cp <path to your xstream jar> app.java`

where `<path to your xstream jar` is the full path to where you put your xstream jar file during downloading.

If you installed the `libxstream-java` debian package using `apt-get` on your Ubuntu system:

`$ javac -cp /usr/share/maven-repo/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.7/xstream-1.4.7.jar app.java`

since in that case the jar is installed in a maven repository on your system.

Comment: On Debian 8 that would be (note that I also add the current directroy at the end `:.`):  `javac -cp /usr/share/java/xstream-1.4.7.jar:. myapplication.java`